# jsPlumb connector between anchors is disappearing with community version 2.2.8(latest)

Tags: javascript, html, svg, workflow, jsplumb

I have created a simple demo version of *horizontal work flow* using jsPlumb library by creating anchors and adding source/target endpoint between those anchors.

everything rendered fine with **jsPlumb 2.0.7**, but when pointed to latest library **jsPlumb 2.2.8**, the connections between the anchors disappeared even though the *arrows* at the end of the connectors are appearing.

**JS connector code:**

```
 var basicType = {
      connector: "StateMachine",
      paintStyle: {
        strokeStyle: "red",
        lineWidth: 5
      },
      hoverPaintStyle: {
        strokeStyle: "blue"
      },
      overlays: [
        "Arrow"
      ]
    };
    instance.registerConnectionType("basic", basicType);
```

**Demo using jsplumb 2.0.7 [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/sfzdb7k3/17/) - Working version**

**Demo using jsplumb 2.2.8 [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/sfzdb7k3/18/) - Faulty version**

any quick help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue resolved from the author(simon porritt) himself outside of SO forum.

so the actual issue was that the style parameter `strokeStyle` being renamed to `stroke` starting from  version **2.2.0**.

**Correct Style format:**

```
paintStyle: { 
     stroke:"blue", //renamed to "stroke" from "strokeStyle"
     strokeWidth:10 
    }
```

here is the [Change log](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/changelog.html) for the same on official jsPlumb site.